# Excel VBA to select header from Sheet1 at A1 to the end of the table, and paste it to another Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

This is the `Sheet1` and I've renamed it to `s1`

[image]

Then, I created 2 new sheets, name it as `s2` and `s3`. It works.

```
Sub test()

' 1. Create 2 new sheets, name it as "s2" and "s3"

    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "s2"
    
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "s3"
```

Next step was to copy `A1:C1` from `s1`, and paste it to `s2` and `s3` also at `A1:C1`

```
' 2. Attempt to copy and paste doesn't work yet

    Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Copy
    Sheets("s2").Paste
    Sheets("s3").Paste

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work. Instead of pasting the content of `A1:C1` from `s1`, it just selected from `A1` to the end on sheet `s2` and `s3`.

[image]

Desired output on both `s2` and `s3`

[image]

Comment: You need to specify the worksheet in `Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Copy`. You're implicitly working off of the `ActiveSheet`, which is not `s1`.

Comment: @BigBen `Sheets("s1").Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Copy` ?

Comment: Every single instance of `Range` must be qualified, including the inner ones. A `With` statement might be useful here: `With Sheets("s1")`, `.Range(.Range("A1"), ....`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim WksOldSheet As Worksheet
    Dim WksNewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim BytCounter As Byte
    
    'Setting WksOldSheet as the active sheet. This way we can refer to it _
    even if another sheet is activated.
    Set WksOldSheet = ActiveSheet
    
    'Since we have to basically do the same thing twice, we start a For-Next _
    cycle. Note that it will start with BytCounter equal to 2 and will end with _
    BytCounter equal to 3. Therefore it will be repeated 2 times.
    For BytCounter = 2 To 3
        
        'While creating a new sheet, we set it as WksNewSheet. This way we can _
        easily refer to it.
        Set WksNewSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
        
        'Setting the name of WksNewSheet. We use an hardcoded s and BytCounter.
        WksNewSheet.Name = "s" & BytCounter
        
        'With a With statement we can avoid repeating WksOldsheet.
        With WksOldSheet
            'Copying the header in the new sheet.
            .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Copy WksNewSheet.Range("A1")
            'If we were not to use the With statement, the previous line would have looked like this:
            'WksOldSheet.Range(WksOldSheet.Range("A1"), WksOldSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Copy WksNewSheet.Range("A1")
        End With
        
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Evil Blue Monkey, it works.  I notice that you're using `WksNewSheet.Name = "s" & BytCounter` as the sheets name are `s2` and `s3`. What if the sheet name is random, let say `Task 123` and `Group X` instead of `s2` and `s3`

Comment: If they are "random", you probably will have to hard code them or at least pick them from a source. It might be a range or a variable created via code perhaps via an inputbox.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you please take a look at this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64665469/excel-vba-to-filter-column-cut-the-content-and-paste-it-to-the-other-sheets